# How can I install the Faenza icons for Libreoffice on 14.04?

Tags: libreoffice, faenza

The question says it all. I had a working icon set on LibreOffice 4.1 that got messed up due to an upgrade to 14.04.

How can I install my Faenza icons again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Note: because icons are for the Desktop users (and not server users), the following steps use as little terminal as possible. For noobs: nautilus is the standard file manager.]

1. Download the icon pack from http://dfiles.eu/files/k2dq3mwkq
2. Go to the directory in which you downloaded it, right-click on the zip file and choose "extract here"
3. Navigate in the just extracted folder to "LibreOffice Pack Icons-0.3.8-a-1/LibreOffice  4.1.0 (Sidebar)/Faenza icons LibreOffice 4.1.0"
4. Open a terminal and type `sudo nautilus /usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/`
5. In the Nautilus window that opens rename `images_crystal.zip` to something like `images_crystal.zip_old` and keep the Nautilus windows open.
6. Copy the `images_crystal.zip` file from the Faenza icons LibreOffice 4.1.0 folder you have kept open and paste it in the windows displaying /usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/.
7. Close nautilus and open LibreOffice.
8. In LibreOffice choose Tools/Options/View, then select Crystal as the icon style and voila:

[image: Faenza icons in LibreOffice theme installed]

Comment: file was removed

Comment: You're right. Did you find a copy of the file somewhere online?

Comment: Any luck with a different link?

Comment: Have not used this icon set in a while. Maybe http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/Faenza-Icons-173323228 is a good starting point? If not, the sifr icon set (other answer) might be an option.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the Sifr icon set (very similar to the Faenza set depicted in another answer):

[image]

Much more simply by using the PPA available for Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style-sifr
```

To chose this icon set, then go to `Tools > Options > LibreOffice > View` and then select "Sifr" under "Icon size and style" drop-down.

Comment: Nice answer. The Sifr set is not as nice as the Faenza set, though. But that is a matter of taste. It is definitely easier to install. Have an upvote!

Comment: Thanks. :) Like you, I prefer (marginally) Faenza, but the ease of using Sifr makes it my normal choice. Thanks for the write-up, though: before Sifr this used to drive me nuts. :)